# Best practices for guice injector usage

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

From the Guice docs:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    /*
     * Guice.createInjector() takes your Modules, and returns a new Injector
     * instance. Most applications will call this method exactly once, in their
     * main() method.
     */
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new BillingModule());

    /*
     * Now that we've got the injector, we can build objects.
     */
    BillingService billingService = injector.getInstance(BillingService.class);
    ...
  }
```

So, after all of this workarond if i will need to get instance of my BillingService out of main class - i need to keep link on injector variable to do this?

I mean, in other class, i'll need to do something like this:

```
BillingService billingService = MainClass.injector.getInstance(BillingService.class)
```

To get instance of BillingService? This doesn't seems elegant for me, is there any other ways to do this?

Comment: "In other class" you'll need to do that, but if you can get the instance of your other class from `injector`, your other class can express its deps as `@Inject` fields or `@Inject` constructor parameters. This makes Olivier's answer correct: You shouldn't need to keep or access your injector explicitly, unless you or your framework creates objects outside of your dependency injector.

Answer (score 3):

This is why modules exist.

Just add several modules to your `createInjector(...)` method.

If your other class is referenced through your modules, you can simply write the following:

```
class PaymentService {
  @Inject BillingService billingService;
}
```

What I would do is using an "application" class starting everything up, like you have your `main` method, just inside Guice-configured classes.